# App stuck on splash screen using Flutter in Android Studio with Firebase

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

After getting rid of errors and using Flutter Clean to tidy up my app, I am getting the following error in my RUN section and the app is stuck on the FLutter splash screen.

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device sdk gphone64 x86 64...
Restarted application in 578ms.
E/flutter ( 6726): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)
E/flutter ( 6726): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:248:7)
E/flutter ( 6726): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6726): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25)
E/flutter ( 6726): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6726): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)
E/flutter ( 6726): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6726): #3      main (package:plancel/main.dart:8:1)
E/flutter ( 6726): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6726):
```

I have re-added the latest google-services.json, ensured all errors are resolved, but I can't seem to find the answer.